# The term when a person working in a hospital ask you what you want to eat?

Tags: synonyms

What do you call it when an aide or nurse or other person working in a hospital 
takes your meal order.

For example I want a better term or the verb for

"..hands out and collects the menus and records what patients want to eat."

Comment: ***Order***: A request made by a customer at a restaurant for a portion of food.

Comment: You use the phrase "takes your order" in the question - are you trying to get a technical definition of that phrase?  "the process of writing down what the diner has chosen from the menu, along with any modifications or special requests."??

Comment: correct,  i wan to know the process of recording it .

Comment: It's right there in your first sentence: "a waiter takes your order." It sounds, though, from your example sentence, like you may be looking at a process in a hospital in which someone collects menus on which patients have selected meal choices. This process could be called something different. Are you asking specifically about a hospital setting?    That is, something like "One of the jobs of the aide is to collect the menus and record what patients want to eat?"

Comment: To write down an order. But I wonder: does such a term exist in your language?

Comment: in a hospital setting . please

Comment: I edited your question.  If you don't like what I did, roll back my edit or edit my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The *process* may vary from hospital to hospital, and within a hospital may vary depending how sick and/or capable of communication the patient is and whether the patient is on a special diet or otherwise requires special supervision by the dietician.  In the only hospital I have been in, I was supposed to telephone my order -- to a real person -- and give her my order.  If I had not phoned about three hours before the meal, someone phoned me and asked for my order.

Now, to answer your question about the English.  In the simple case it is ***takes the patient's meal order***.  My reference: being asked several times by a nurse or nurse's aide "Have you phoned in your dinner order yet?"

The more complicated case probably involves referring to the dietician's orders for the patient.

Comment: @AminulSchuster If that has answered your question, you should (1) upvote the answer; & (2) accept the answer (by clicking the shadow 'tick' mark, if I recall correctly). That will award points to the person who has given you your answer.

Comment: @TrevorD Thanks.  The OP may not have enough rep to upvote, but he can accept.

Comment: OK. I didn't realise that there is a minimum rep for upvoting - I knew there is for adding Comments.